# Ember.js missing modules?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying Ember.js out and facing some wierd issues . .

Initially i forked ember.js form [Ember-GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads)

and imported lib folder with jQuery, Handlebar, Ember libraries.

That Ember version have undefined Ember.View , Ember.Router, Ember.Route even i can find them inside source code, they appear undefined.

Anyway if i use some other versions of ember packages : [Download packages](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads)

i can find version with Ember.View and Ember.Router BUT without Ember.Controller and Ember.Route

*This also varies in same versions of file in minifed and not-minifed versions wtf*

Why are these modules undefined when i can find them inside Ember Source code ?

And why this varies so much from version to version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution:

- Download: emberjs from the homepage at http://emberjs.com/
- Download: handlebars from their homepage at http://handlebarsjs.com/
- Download: jquery 1.9.0 at http://jquery.com/download/

In your index.html, before `</body>` input:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

In app.js, input:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

// Do some ember stuff here, like making a mapping on the Router
```

Enjoy!

Comment: There's no need to `App.initialize();` any more, but all of the rest is fine. I don't see why you'd be missing components. It's inexplicable.

Comment: Removed the initialize() step. Thanks for notifying, didn't know that myself ;)

Comment: conclusion: don't use starter kits and github numerous revisions.

The one from main site is valid.