# Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null on ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get started with ember.js, so I've followed the tutorials as closely as I can. I currently have this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
   Test
 </script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>

</html>
```

Where app.js is:

```
App = Em.Application.create();
```

and in Chrome I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:18
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Change to an un–minified version of ember.js so you get a meaningful error message.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- follow my instructions here: [Ember.js missing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801865/ember-js-missing-modules/14802112#14802112)
- respect the order of the `script` tags (jquery -> handlebars -> ember)
- create a `body` tag, ember needs to be able to write to it
- put the `script` tags right before the `</body>` tag

Resulting in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bitshiftcop.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      Test
    </script>    

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script src="ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```